# Touchcreen display problem Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dell, touchscreen

I have Dell Inspirion 11. 3000 series.

Display is touchscreen and I switched from Windows to Ubuntu 20.04.

Since then I have problems with display, it randomly displays something I didn't click.
It's quite often too, and annoyingly shows in the middle of some work.

So, it is like I clicked something, anything on the screen.

I have turned off touchscreen at one point and it helped, but is there any other way to keep the touchscreen on and not getting this errors?

Thank you.